# What gets submitted to the database is just the entry of "other" and not what i typed in manually?

Tags: javascript, php, html

When i select the option value of "other" in my dropdown lis the form row below appears and allows me to type a manual cemetery but what gets submitted to the database is just the entry of "other" and not what i typed in manually?

```
  <script>
    function handleSelect() {
      var selected = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
      var details = document.getElementById("other-details");

      if (selected === "other") {
        details.classList.remove("d-none");
        details.classList.add("d-block");
      } else {
        details.classList.remove("d-block");
        details.classList.add("d-none");
      }
    }
  </script>


  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 offset-md-3 mx-auto">
      <label class="control-label custom_label col-xs-12">Cemetery</label>
      <select name="cemetery" class="form-control" id="mySelect" onchange="handleSelect();">
        <option value="select" selected="selected">Select Cemetery</option>
        <option value="Akatarawa">Akatarawa</option>
        <option value="Taita">Taita</option>
        <option value="Wainuiomata">Wainuiomata</option>
        <option value="Whenua Tapu">Whenua Tapu</option>
        <option value="Makara">Makara</option>
        <option value="Karori">Karori</option>
        <option value="St Johns">St Johns</option>
        <option value="Awa Tapu">Awa Tapu</option>
        <option value="Paraparaumu">Paraparaumu</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-row d-none" id="other-details">
    <div class="form-group col-md-6 offset-md-3 mx-auto">
      <input type="text" id="other" class="form-control" name="" placeholder="Enter other Cemetery" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Missing an important part, the one that shows your insert into DB

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `name` of the input to `cemetery`.

```
<input type="text" id="other" class="form-control" name="cemetery" placeholder="Enter other Cemetery" />
```

This may work, but not a good practise.

I suggest you to do something like following

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="other" class="form-control" name="other-cemetery" placeholder="Enter other Cemetery" />
```

**PHP**

```
if($_POST["cemetery"] == "other"){
    $cemetery = $_POST["other-cemetery"];
}
```

**Update:** The first solution that I gave may not work in other cases. So add the following line to `handleSelect()` function. (Not selected case)

```
document.getElementById("other").value = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dum, combining that link of JS and setting the Value of the "other" drop down to empty.

Example:  `<option value="">Other</option>`

This has resolved my issue. Many thanks